# navigating between the tabs in navigation drawer with pager sliding strip using sherlock fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using [Navigationdrawerpagerslidingstrip tutorial](https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip). I have 3 tabs in that when I click a button in first tab it should redirect to 2nd tab or 3rd tab using `getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);` . I have checked the following:
[Action Bar .selectTab() and .setSelectedNavigationItem() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409330/action-bar-selecttab-and-setselectednavigationitem-not-working), 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/240 and many other examples from github. 
Can anyone suggest where I am doing mistake .
The error I am getting is:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>   at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.setSelectedNavigationItem(ActionBarImpl.java:356)
>   at com.example.example.List$ListItemViewAdapter$1.onClick(OrdersList.java:253)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)